# Date data into Year and month by using lambda function - IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, indexing, lambda

I'm trying to create a column 'year' and 'month' from 'order_date' by using str.split and a lambda function. I successfully created the 'year' column. However, I keep getting below error for 'month' column. Please help!

> IndexError: string index out of range

I split the string by a hyphen:
I filled N/A with '0':
I created the year column by using a lambda function:
I used the same logic to create the month column but didn't work:

```
orders2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,'2020-07-24 19:46:36 -0400'],[2,'2020-06-25 20:29:20 -0400'],[3,0]],columns=['order_number','order_date'])
orders2['date'] = orders2.order_date.str.split('-')
orders2.date.fillna('0',inplace=True)
orders2['year'] = orders2.apply(lambda row: row['date'][0],axis=1)
orders2['month'] = orders2.apply(lambda row: row['date'][1],axis=1)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your life easy by choosing python over pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

orders2 = pd.DataFrame([
        [1,'2020-07-24 19:46:36 -0400'],
        [2,'2020-06-25 20:29:20 -0400'],
        [3,0]],columns=['order_number','order_date']
        )

orders2['year'] = ''
orders2['month'] = ''
for index, row in orders2.iterrows():
    try:
        year = str(row["order_date"]).split('-')[0]
        month = str(row["order_date"]).split('-')[1]
    except:
        year = '0'
        month = '0'
   
    orders2.at[index, 'year'] = year
    orders2.at[index, 'month'] = month

print(orders2)
```

output:

```
    order_number                 order_date  year month
0             1  2020-07-24 19:46:36 -0400  2020    07
1             2  2020-06-25 20:29:20 -0400  2020    06
2             3                          0     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! what about the month column? I can't find a way to get the month column...

Comment: @Data_Yoda i have edited, as you have 0 values also, so I put a try and except, you can further modified it from here as per your need.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! this works perfectly! + a try and except! elegant!